# Oracle - Updating with Join 3 tables

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have 3 tables: inventory as table 1, buy_transaction as table 2, and po_data as table 3.

These are the queries I tried:

```
update vnt_inventory_tab.quantity
set vnt_inventory_tab.quantity = quantity + (SELECT pdt.quantity
FROM   vnt_po_data_tab pdt JOIN vnt_buy_trnsctn_tab bt ON pdt.po_no = bt.po_no
WHERE  pdt.po_no = :p_po_no)
where VNT_INVENTORY_TAB.CODE = VNT_PO_DATA_TAB.CODE;
```

It return as table doesn't exist. I'm not sure where I put wrong because when I do the sub-query it returns exactly the number I want to update into the inventory.

Help me pls

Comment: Please show the complete error messages.

Comment: [Error] Execution (1: 76): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: update vnt_inventory_tab.quantity  -> update vnt_inventory_tab

Comment: Looks like the final condition `vnt_inventory_tab.code = vnt_po_data_tab.code` belongs inside the subquery, because `vnt_inventory_tab` doesn't have a column named `vnt_po_data_tab.code`.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax UPDATE statement requires only **table-Name** (not a specific column like yours) after the keyword update. More details see [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html)